# Setting fields of an Android Class using edit text

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a `Message` Object to a `reyclerview` whose input is taken from the user.

The way I'm going about this is by having `mainActivity` use `startActivity` on an `intent` that activates a new class.

In the new class, there are `editTexts` a user can use to set fields of the class. Those fields of the class then can be used to create an instance of the object to be added to the `RecyclerView` in `mainActivity`. Here is some relevant code.

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent launchFiller= fillaMessageActivity.createIntent();
    startActivity(launchFiller);
    messages.add(fillaMessageActivity.createMessage());
    }
    });
```

In `fillaMessageActivity`:

```
EditText inputName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillName);

EditText inputDate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillDate);
EditText inputMessage=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillContent);

String nameinput=inputName.getText().toString();
String dateinput=inputDate.getText().toString();
String content=inputMessage.getText().toString();

public Message createMessage(){
Message a= new Message(nameinput, dateinput, content);
return a;
}
```

My code in `fillaMessageActivity` works, but not in `mainActivity`, as I get the error that

> the non-static method `createMessage` within class
>   `fillamessageactivity` cannot be referenced from a static context.

Making the method static results in its own set of problems.

How can I modify the fields of a class using  an `edittexts` within the class?

Comment: What class is your `FloatingActionButton` in? Above you say "In the new class, there are editTexts a user can use to set fields of the class. ". So I'm trying to figure out why are you launching an Intent for a Activity the user is already in?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. The FAB is in mainActivity. I'm trying to launch a fillaMessageActivity from mainActivity so that I can input fields into fillaMessageActivity. Those fields will be used to create a Message object that can be added to the recyclerView in mainActivity.